# javascript minification how to handle function renaming declared as var

Tags: javascript, minify

just to simplify the issue I am facing
I have a xyz.js which is compressed before production usage 
Now I have a top level function defined inside xyz.js and inside it private functions
ex.
    var foo1234 = function(){
    ...
    }

now I use foo1234() in other places within the same file. But after minification foo1234() gets renamed and my code which accesses foo() now fails. How can I avoid this and still do proper js compression?

any help or standard practice to avoid this will be great.

Comment: You have to tell the minifier to not rename the functions that are part of the public API of your library. I don't know which minifier you are using, but there should be an option for that.

Comment: You can concat all your files together and then minify if `foo1234` is local and the compiler will handle it from there. If you're exposing it you should probably do `window.foo1234`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you use an existing minifier, such as Google's [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/).  It does JavaScript-to-JavaScript optimization and minification.

As you've discovered, variable renaming is not such a trivial task, and doing it optimally is even harder.  You can save yourself a lot of headaches using an open-source tool, while also gaining other optimization benefits.